# Copy file and not dir with the same name in docker 2-stage build

Tags: docker, go, dockerfile, docker-multi-stage-build

In the following `Dockerfile`

```
WORKDIR /app
RUN go build -ldflags "-s -w" -a -installsuffix cgo -o tool-web ./tool-web

...

FROM scratch
COPY --from=build /app/tool-web /app/tool-web
```

turns out the `COPY` directive copies the directory `tool-web` and not the binary.

Is there a way to specify to the `COPY` that the binary is to be copied?

Comment: You can't have a file and directory with the same name. I'd check what the go build command actually created.

Answer (score 1):

Per the `go` command [documentation](https://pkg.go.dev/cmd/go):

> The -o flag forces build to write the resulting executable or object to the named output file or directory, instead of the default behavior described in the last two paragraphs. If the named output is an existing directory or ends with a slash or backslash, then any resulting executables will be written to that directory.

Thus, if you use `-o tool-web` and `./tool-web/` is an existing directory, your output binary will be written as a file within the `tool-web` directory. A decent guess is your binary may have been installed as `./tool-web/main`.

To fix this, two easy approaches would be:

1. Figure out the path your binary is installed as, and adjust `COPY` to use that path as the source

   - `COPY --from=build /app/tool-web/main /app/tool-web`
2. Or, change the `-o` to write to a different filename, and then adjust `COPY` to use that name as the source

   - `-o tool-web-binary`
   - `COPY --from=build /app/tool-web-binary /app/tool-web`